# Can rails generate a thumbnail picture of a video?

Tags: video

How Guys
I'm working on a project that need display same thing like this, I think it make sense to use some tools to automatically generate the thumbnails and save them in the database when I submit a video

I'm also want some similar rails code that do the youtube alike function, could anyone give me suggestion rails code website.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What format is your video in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out :
http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2009/2/22/video-thumbnails-with-ffmpeg-and-paperclip
hope it helps... :)

Comment: thanks gillyb, This is a great solution, but how can i install FFmpeg in Heroku alike app host

Comment: Well, now you have a different problem altogether... I'm not familiar with Heroku app host service, but it probably mostly depends on what hosting package you're paying for. Usually they don't let you do much when you pay for the cheapest ones, but if you upgrade to a dedicated server or something better, than you might be able to. Maybe you could email some other hosting companies (including yours) and tell them you would like to purchase hosting plan but need this plugin and want to know how it could be possible... Good Luck!

Comment: You could also look into using http://zencoder.com/ for video transcoding. Then you would be able to keep the cheapest (free) Heroku plan.

Comment: Hi @yozloy, how you manage to work with ffmpeg on heroku in the end?

Answer (score 5):

I created a gem to ease interaction between Rails apps and FFMPEG: https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg

Comment: how does that work with heroku? I am getting 'sh: ffmpeg: not found' any additional gem required?

Comment: You need to install ffmpeg package using your OS package manager.
YMMV with Heroku though, haven't use Heroku yet!

Answer (score 5):

Its easier if you use directly ffmpeg, you have to install first ffmpeg and the you can call with this line`system "ffmpeg -itsoffset -1 -i #{path} -s 320x240 -y -vframes 1 -f image2 -an 'app/assets/images/#{@video.title}.jpg'"` 
-itsoffset is the time you want the thumbnail
-i is the input file
-an is the outpout file

I take a look for other options and this is the faster way to do.

Comment: can you give some more details . how to use this directly in the model itself